# function pointer containing the struct itself as parameter being inside the same struct

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

```
typedef struct
{
    int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    int (*division_mode_x)(int i,int x1,int x2,SpriteGrid grid);
    int (*division_mode_y)(int i,int y1,int y2);
}SpriteGrid;
```

Do you think this is a valid way to use function pointers inside struct?

**Note :** Please don't say try and see it for yourself. There is no problem with compilation. I just wanna know if this is a standard property of the C language. Will it also compile in other compilers?

Comment: using function pointer inside a struct  its a common practice in C, you can look here https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/include/linux/input.h#L121 at struct input_dev for example

Comment: This is essentially the way to do in C what OO languages do automatically with the `this` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't compile on gcc, clang or tinycc, and it shouldn't.
Before the typedef ends, SpriteGrid is not a thing so you can't use it. Forward declaring the struct (with a tag) and the typedef should fix it.

```
typedef struct SpriteGrid SpriteGrid; 
typedef struct SpriteGrid /*this typedef is redundant now*/
{
    int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    int (*division_mode_x)(int i,int x1,int x2,SpriteGrid grid);
    int (*division_mode_y)(int i,int y1,int y2);
}SpriteGrid;
```

Alternatively, you can do

```
typedef struct SpriteGrid
{
    int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    //without the forward typedef `SpriteGrid` isn't usable
    //here yet, but `struct SpriteGrid` is 
    int (*division_mode_x)(int i,int x1,int x2,struct SpriteGrid grid);
    int (*division_mode_y)(int i,int y1,int y2);
}SpriteGrid;
```

relying on the fact that a tag becomes usable immediately after `struct tag`.